# Como listar todos os nomes das tabelas do Access?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio-2013, oledb

Oi, estou querendo exibir os nomes das tabelas que estão dentro do arquivo Access e jogar para uma variável. Como eu posso fazer isso? A própria plataforma C# fornece atributos para que eu possa fazer isso? Estou usando a referência [System.Data.OleDb](http://using%20System.Data.OleDb).

Abaixo é o código que estou tentando pegar as tabelas, mas não dá certo.

```
 string path = "./info.mdb";
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", path));    
 conn.Open();
 OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tabela, conn);
 OleDbDataReader reader = odc.ExecuteReader();
 var tabelas = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Acima na variável tabela, não encontro a lista de tabelas que fica no arquivo `info.mdb`.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms135983(v=vs.110).aspx) que lista as tabelas (e outras estruturas do MDB) que você deve utilizar é um método do Connection e não do reader. O [getSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do reader serve para ler o schema da tabela definida na query

Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer a leitura de todas as tabelas de um MDB

```
// Microsoft Access provider factory
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

DataTable userTables = null;
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
  // c:\test\test.mdb
  connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\test\\test.mdb";
  // We only want user tables, not system tables
  string[] restrictions = new string[4];
  restrictions[3] = "Table";

  connection.Open();

  // Get list of user tables
  userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
}

List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
    tableNames.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
```

## Nota:

O restrictions é um array que funciona como um filtro. Caso nada seja passado nele, todas as estrutruras (tabelas, views, filtros, formularios, etc.) serão retornados. Como OleDB é um provider genérico (serve tanto para MDB quanto para XLS, DBF, etc) o restrictions vai depender da base. Deixo aqui a tradução não oficial da documentação:

> O restrictionValues parâmetro pode fornecer n profundidade de valores
>   que são especificadas na coleção de restrições para uma coleção
>   específica. Para definir valores em uma restrição de determinado e não
>   definir os valores das outras restrições, você precisa definir as
>   restrições anteriores para nulo e, em seguida, coloque o valor
>   apropriado para a restrição que você deseja especificar um valor para.
>
> Um exemplo disso é a coleção de "Tabelas". Se a coleção "Tabelas" tem
>   três restrições (banco de dados, proprietário e nome de tabela), e
>   você quiser obter somente as tabelas associadas com o proprietário
>   "Carl", você deve passar os valores a seguir (no mínimo): null,
>   "Carl". Se um valor de restrição não for passado, os valores padrão
>   são usados para essa restrição. Isso é o mesmo mapeamento como passar
>   null, que é diferente da passagem de uma cadeia de caracteres vazia
>   para o valor do parâmetro. Nesse caso, a cadeia de caracteres vazia
>   ("") é considerado o valor para o parâmetro especificado.

Comment: Ótimo! excelente! +1